# Magento : Allow the customer to add a comment when adding a product to cart

Tags: magento, cart

I'm working on a Magento shop and I want to give the customers the possibility to add a comment when they put a product in cart.

The comment can contain specifications about the ordrered product. It must be visible in the checkout, in the confirmation email and in the admin sales interface.

Is there a way to do that with the standard Magento configuration? Or does a module exist?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this extension, See the screenshots.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/brainvire-order-comment-order-comment-magento-extension.html

This may helpful for you, I have used this in a project, it works well.

But as you saying customer should add comment while adding product, you need to customize this extenion a bit.

Cheers :-)